# UIImage view matrix transform in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to change imageView matrix on iOS, not by CATransform3D,not by MeshTransform , but change vertices of whole image, using transformation matrix. On Android I used from Matrix library method called 'setPolyToPoly'. Can anyone tell me how to do it in iOS. The effect is like 'setPolyToPoly' method from Android?
Or am I thinking wrong.it should be use Metal or OpenGL?[image]
[image][image]
I added 3 pictures. I hope everyone can understand the effect I want. 
In addition, I also want to know how to rely on 3 points on a picture to intercept a triangle UIImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenCV for that. You can find a easy UIImage category [here](https://gist.github.com/tomas789/f54080e88e8cfa187228322823328c01) (Note this is objective c++ code).

```
OpenCV -> UIImage
cv::Mat mat /* = ... */;
UIImage* image = [UIImage fromCvMat:mat];
UIImage -> OpenCV

UIImage* image /* = ... */;
cv::Mat mat = [UIImage toCvMat:image];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
After 2 days of learning, it seems that this effect can also be achieved through CIFilter.
I will try it later,and compare the effects they achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the CIFilter "Perspective Transform". Original:

[image]

After the transform:

[image]

Things to keep in mind:

- The coordinate system of CIFilter is flipped with respect to iOS (that is, the origin is at the lower left, not the upper left)
- If you want to do this sort of thing in real time, as the user stretches the image, you'll need to use Metal; CIContext rendering won't cut it

Comment: While changing in real time, I also need to change the transparency of the image. Can metal do it?
Can you give me some suggestions to learn metal in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to do Perspective transformation, there are many ways, but in combination with what I ultimately need to make, I used OpenCV, and also learned computer graphics in the process.
By the way, in fact, what I need to do is affine transformation. IOS and Android are a bit different. The Android library method passes 3 points as affine and 4 points as transmission. XD
Thank you friends for your answers.